# tcpdump error message "That device doesn't support monitor mode"

Tags: linux, arm, linux-device-driver, tcpdump, device-tree

Running Linux on a Xilinx ZCU102 development board. When using a 1000BASE-X & Tri-Mode Ethernet Mac. I can send pings out of the Ethernet port, but when I run tcpdump to try and show that packets are coming into the system... I get a strange error from tcpdump.

```
tcpdump -I eth1
tcpdump: eth1: That device doesn't support monitor mode
```

Curious if anyone has any insight on this error message from tcpdump.

How does tcpdump know if the device supports monitor mode?
Does it look for something in the eth1 device node in the device tree?

Comment: you read the man page right? "Put the interface in "monitor mode"; this is supported  only  on IEEE 802.11 Wi-Fi interfaces, and supported only on some operating systems."   but you are wired right?  what if you run tcpdump without the -I?  You should then see the packets coming into the system.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the '**-i**' option for non-"IEEE 802.11" interface:

```
tcpdump -i eth0
```

If you want to filter a specific data link type, run `tcpdump -L -i eth0` to get the list of supported types and use a particular type like `tcpdump -y EN1000MB -i eth0`.

Comment: Wow... I was confused, because ping uses a -I flag to select an interface. For tcpdump one must use -i to select an interface. Thanks for helping me figure this out. Very dumb on my part. Hopefully this post can help others avoid that same confusion.